# Volume group not found after hard shutdown due to beveage spilled on the computer

Tags: partition, lvm, cryptsetup

This afternoon, I made a stupid move and some beverage spilled over my computer. I did not notice it directly, but when I came back the PC was shutdown. The computer was not on battery.

I tried to restart the computer but it did not work. I dismantled the back, wiped a few drops. Let the computer dried an hour.

The computer finally powered on, but something weird happen with the bios and a reinitialisation happened. Then, after a restart, it says it was not able to found a bootable device.

I went into the BIOS configuration, change the bootable device to grub.efi and then restart. It did boot, and after selecting my system on the GRUB interface, the encryption system says it could not found my volume group.

```
Volume group <name> not found
Cannot process volum group <name>
cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device <UUID-partition>
```

After few minutes I have a initramfs console, and now I am lost to understand the issue. In `/dev/mapper` there is an empty file called `control`. The file `/etc/fstab` is empty which I think is weird. The content of `cryptroot/crypttab` is:

```
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=<UUID> none luks, discard
```

And I am unable to find in `/dev` something called `nvme0n1p3_crypt` or `nvme0n1p3`. I don't have access either to `/boot` or `/home`. I suppose it is because the mounted point is different from `/`.

I am quite uncertain to know whether it is a software issue or a physical one. I only have on hard-drive which is an SSD.

Comment: Have you tried booting a live USB to see if your hard drive is fried?

Comment: Not yet, funny thing, I don't have any key USB at home. I will have to get one tomorrow.

Comment: The output of `fdisk -l` does not show my hard-drive from the USB key. I don't really know how to diagnostic the issue now.

Comment: The message I see is SATa link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300) but I can't figure out the meaning of thei error code.

Comment: That unfortunately sounds like damage to either the motherboard or the hard drive. If you can pull the hard drive and see if it works in another machine/enclosure

Answer (score 1):

I was able to understand the issue. There is no material damage. The issue was mentioned on a Reddit post such as this one: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/ax6mga/arch_cant_find_my_nvme_disk/ and is explained here for example https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_2-in-1_(9365) .

Following the first restart, I suspect something happened in the BIOS such as a reset factory and the SATA controller option was set to `RAID` which roughly says: the BIOS is allowed to see the hard-drive but not the OS. Setting this option to `AHCI`, everything worked as usual.

Comment: thanks, had the exact same problem with BIOS having reset to `IDE` without me noticing. changing the SATA option back to `AHCI` solved the issue of the lvm group not being found.